# load() jquery, me recarga varias veces la url

Tags: html, jquery

tengo un problema con la funcion load() de jquery.

1. Al darle click al boton la primera vez, me carga la pagina,
2. Al darle click por segunda vez me cargar dos vece la pagina (visto en el depurador , sección red).
3. Al darle click por tercera vez me carga tres veces la pagina
4. Así sucesivamente, haciendo que la pagina llegue a tardar demasiado en cargarse.
5. los script que tengo en la pagina que se carga (ver-ente.php) también se ejecutan ya que están en un $(document).ready().
6. el load(), se ejecuta desde el .content-inner

```
$(document).on("click", ".ver-detalles", function() {
              
        id_ente = $(this).attr("id-ente");
      
        CargarContenido('vistas/ver-ente.php', 'content-inner');

        
});}
```

aqui esta la funcion

```
function CargarContenido(pagina_php, contenedor) {
   $("." + contenedor).load(pagina_php);
}
```

¿Por qué sucede?
¿Cómo evitarlo?

gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: despues de que actualizaste tu codigo... estoy seguro que tiene un twice event firing ... y ese tipo de comportamiento casi no se pueden reproducir en otros entornos ... mas que en tu propio desarrollo. fijate mi respuesta trata de implementarla y valida si soluciona tu problema ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probé la función que me dio [ArcanisGK507](/users/46896), y me quedo con esta línea:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Finalmente mi código queda así:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ver-detalles", function() {
              
        id_ente = $(this).attr("id-ente");
      
        CargarContenido('vistas/ver-ente.php', 'content-inner');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        
});}
```

Por otra parte, estuve indagando en la documentación de jquery, y también sirve la función `one()` que resulta igual de eficaz para solucionar la sobrecargar de archivos.

Quedando resuelto el problema con el siguiente código:

```
$(document).one("click", ".ver-detalles", function() {
              
        id_ente = $(this).attr("id-ente");
      
        CargarContenido('vistas/ver-ente.php', 'content-inner');
            
});}
```

Comment: felicidades muy bien, no me llevo con ese metodo ... nunca lo uso ... incluso ya he comensado a abandonar jquery XD

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

estoy casi seguro que es un `twice event firing` puedes solucionarlo con:

```javascript
function StopProp(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
$(document).off('click.ic', '.ver-detalles');
$(document).unbind('click.ic', '.ver-detalles');
$(document).on("click.ic", ".ver-detalles", function(event) {
        window.StopProp(event);
        consola.log('Ejecutado 1 sola vez');   
});
```

recomendaria el uso de namespace en los eventos `.ic` en realidad es cualquier texto para diferencia el tipo de click que quieres manipular...